# Set Theory Problem: Implications

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-writing

Let $S$ be a non-empty subset of real numbers.

If $\forall a \in \mathbb{Z}, \exists b \in S, b > a$, then is it true that $\forall a \in S, \exists b \in S, b > a$?

Answer (score 1):

If $a\in S$, can you find an integer larger than $a$?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by this.

Comment: Start with a number $a\in S$. There is an integer $n\in\mathbb{Z}$ such that $a<n$. Now what do you know about $S$?

Comment: Ah, I see  thanks!

Comment: What about the converse?

Comment: @JeraldTenor consider $S=(0,1)$